# Spring WebClient GET request fails with "Moved Permanently. Redirecting to"

Tags: spring-webflux, vpn, cisco, spring-webclient

I killed more than one day on this issue and could not understand root cause.

So, I am trying to make simple get request with WebClient from Webflux

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

Mono<String> stringMono = webClient.get()
    .uri(urlWhichAvailableOnlyUnderVPN)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class);

stringMono.subscribe(response -> System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + response));
```

I am expecting to get xml string from this response but actual output is "RESPONSE: Moved Permanently. Redirecting to another_url"

From browser (google chrome) and Postman I am able to request the **urlWhichAvailableOnlyUnderVPN** (from code above) and there response is expected xml.

One interesting thing that when I disable my company VPN and try to request URL in browser it responses with "Moved permanently 301". This is strange.

Another interesting thing that the code above is working on my teammate's computer perfectly. We are using almost the same environment and version of Spring Webflux.

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure webclient to follow redirectz

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                   .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                            HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)
                    ))
                    .build();
```

Comment: I have already tried this and this works. However, it is not what I actually need - I don't need redirection. As example, with connected vpn my browser is not trying to redirect

Comment: Your browser gets redirected, you just don’t see it, its hidden ”under the hood”

Comment: @Aslan sorry then i dont understand what you want. Redirection is coming from server which say hey remember address you requesting is actually moved to new address. Browser will respect that and follow, WebClient by default dont for cases when you need to do extra logic before redirect